# CMD not running all users stated in JMeter thread group

Tags: cmd, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm trying to run a test of 50,000 concurrent users accessing a webpage in JMeter, however running this in CMD doesn't seem to run the complete 50k users. Instead it completes at around 12k users.

I am new to JMeter, so I've tried to keep the test simple with the following:

**1. Thread group:**

- 50000 users
- ramp up period - 5000
- loop count  - 1
- duration - 1800 seconds
- same user on each iteration = checked
- redirect automatically = checked
- follow redirects = unchecked
- use keepalive = checked

**2. Throughput controller:**

- 100% execution

**3. HTTP request - standard url**

**4. Gaussian Random Timer:**

- deviation - 500ms
- constant delay - 2500ms

**5. HTTP cache manager - no changes**

**6. HTTP cookie manager - no changes**

**7. Response Assertion - 200 response code**

So it looks like this:

[how it looks in jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7LTU.png)

I thought the issue was do with the memory size so I increased the heap size from 1gb to 4gb but its not really made a difference.

If the solution is a lot simpler please do let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have duration 1800 and ramp-up period of 5000. If you want to "see" all users - you need to set the duration to be more or equal to the ramp-up period. For example you might want to ramp-up for 5000 seconds and then hold the load for another 1800 seconds, in that case your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) should be configured like this:

[image]

Also make sure that loop count is set to `-1`

I also don't think you will be able to get 5000 users with 4 GB of heap, even if you're following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html), most probably you will need to consider going for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)